# how to set same port on fastapi and eureka?

Tags: python, fastapi, netflix-eureka

I want the same port on uvicorn and eureka configuration, I have search a lot and only found this link https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/761 but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from com.controladores import controladorRouter


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await eureka_client.init_async(
        eureka_server="http://eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/",
        app_name="msprueba",
        instance_port=8000,
        instance_host="localhost"
    )
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.include_router(controladorRouter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = uvicorn.Config("com.main:app", host="localhost", port=0)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    server.run()
```

I removed the code from the link only to show the actual code, I find it hard to believe that simple such task is so hard to do with fastapi. Don't get me wrong fastapi is a great tool, only thing is that I come from springboot and this task is much easier to do in springboot, any help?

Comment: I've never used `eureka`, but from what I can understand, it runs a service which listens to a port. Having two services listening to the same port is not possible (you'll need a load balancer). Maybe I'm wrong, but without an error, that's what I can tell from the question